# Python package name for a function call

Tags: python

I have python library (`A`) which integrates with multiple other python libraries.
A function (`X`) in my library (`A`) can be called through any of these other libraries. When in function `X`, I need to determine the name of the library which was used while calling this function.

The function calls could also result from a user having a script which calls one of the integrated libraries, which then in turn calls my library `A`.

How can I do this ?

I tried looking at `inspect.stack()`, but this gives me the names of the files and functions invoked along the call path. How can I know the name of the python library containing these files/functions ?

Comment: It's almost always better to pass the information the function needs as an argument, rather than trying to inspect the source-code context in which it was called.

Comment: Aren't the file names just `<module name>.py`?

Comment: @luther A library name might not match the module name (e.g., "OpenCV" or `opencv-contrib-python` vs `cv2`, for example). That said, this whole thing is not a good idea at all; introspection is fragile, and destroys performance.

Comment: Why do you need to know the name of the library that called your library? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Post the problem you're actually trying to solve and ask how to best address that.

Comment: I need to know the name of the library because I want to measure the usage of the different libraries integrating with my library. This is purely for audit purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @chepner, this seems like breaking the rule that explicit is prefered over implicit, but anyway:

```py
from inspect import currentframe, getmodule

def x():
    # The root module where x defined. i.e for module "a.x" it's ["a"]
    root_modules = __name__.split(".")

    # Rewind until the module is found.
    frame = currentframe()
    while True:
        mod = getmodule(frame)
        root_mod = root_modules.pop()

        if mod.__name__ != root_mod:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Unexpected {mod.__name__=} != {root_mod=}")

        # When root_modules is empty we've finally hit the bottom, and now next
        # `frame.f_back` is the module that called this function.
        frame = frame.f_back
        if not root_modules:
            break

    called_from = getmodule(frame)
    print(
        f"module={called_from.__spec__.name}\n"
        f"filename={called_from.__file__}\n"
    )
```

Now you can run:

```sh
# Content of file src/a/b.py: `from a import x; x()`

ipython -m a.b
# > module=a.b
# > filename=/home/user/src/a/b.py

# Content of file src/c/d/e.py: `from a import x; x()`

ipython -m c.d.e
# > module=c.d.e
# > filename=/home/user/src/c/d/e.py

# Content of file src/f/g.py: `from c.d.e import x; x()`

ipython -m f.g
# > module=f.g
# > filename=/home/user/src/f/g.py
```